# Write out every seconds in a function

Tags: javascript, setinterval

So, I have a function and I want to count the seconds. The function starts count the seconds normally, but when I start the function again, the seconds going faster. I dont know what is this.

```
var seconds = 0;

function newCall() {
  var min = 3000;
  var max = 20000;
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  console.log("TEST - random time: " + rand);
  seconds = 0;
  setInterval(timer, 1000);
  setInterval(newCall, rand);
}

newCall();

function timer() {
  seconds++;
  console.log("test " + seconds);
}
```

Comment: Replace `setInterval` with `setTimeout`

Comment: It doesn't stop the interval started in the previous function call. That means you have two intervals ticking at the same time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The comments on your question explain my answer, but I added two comments in the code to help.
See if the code below is what you want, please.

```js
var seconds = 0;
var time;

function newCall() {
  clearInterval(time); //CLEAR THE INTERVAL TO AVOID MANY INTERVALS AT SAME TIME
  var min = 3000;
  var max = 20000;
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  console.log("TEST - random time: " + rand);
  seconds = 0;
  time = setInterval(timer, 1000); //CHANGED HERE
  setTimeout(newCall, rand);
}

newCall();

function timer() {
  seconds++;  
  console.log("test " + seconds);
}
```

Comment: Got it, thanks. Btw, I wanted to count how many seconds elapse between two newcall function.